# Proguard and HashMap<String, MyObject>

Tags: android, jar, hashmap, obfuscation, proguard

I'm developing some apis for android as a library project and I'd like to export them as an obfuscated jar.

I have various classes but the only public entities are:

- `MyInterface`: An interface listing some methods that the user will have to implement;
- `MyUtilities`: A class with some static methods;
- `MySingleton`: A Singleton (implemented as an enum with a single INSTANCE);
- `MyObject`: A class implementing a particular object I need to handle;

I am new with Obfuscation so I followed some tutorials and read android/proguard docs.

I successfully created a jar from my project and used it in an external application.
I also successfully obfuscated all the non-public classes (so every class apart from the above-mentioned) and it still continue working.

---

Now my problem:

One of the methods specifed in `MyInterface` is

```
public void getObject(HashMap<String, MyObject>);
```

before obfuscation the user could add `implements MyInterface` to his activity/class and (auto) generate the implementation of the the interface methods, in particular:

```
@Override
public void getObject(HashMap<String, MyObject> hashmap){
  // User implementation
}
```

After having obfuscated the jar, when I add `implements MyInterface` to a user activity and auto-generate the methods implementations, I get:

```
@Override
public void getObject(HashMap hashmap){
  // User implementation
}
```

So without HashMap types. I honestly don't know why this happens..
I expected to see also the HashMap types because both `String` and `MyObject` are kept.

It still works also without HashMap types, but I have to cast it to a `Hasmap<String, MyObject>`

This is my proguard conf file (generated by the proguard gui tool):

```
-injars inAPIs.jar
-outjars 'obfAPIs.jar'

-libraryjars /My/android/SDK/Path/platforms/android-15/android.jar
-libraryjars /My/android/SDK/Path/tools/support/annotations.jar
-libraryjars /My/android/SDK/Path/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-15/libs/effects.jar
-libraryjars /My/android/SDK/Path/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-15/libs/maps.jar
-libraryjars /My/android/SDK/Path/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-15/libs/usb.jar

-overloadaggressively


-keep class my.package.MyObject {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}

-keep public class my.package.MyUtilities {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}

-keep interface  my.package.MyInteface {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}

-keep public class my.package.MySingleton {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}

-keep,allowshrinking public class my.package.MyInterface {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}

-keep,allowshrinking public class my.package.MyObject

-keep,allowshrinking public class my.package.MyUtils

-keep,allowshrinking public enum  my.package.MySingleton {
    public <fields>;
    public <methods>;
}
```

Comment: This has to do with type erasure in Java, I guess? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Proguard docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepattributes), you may want to add the following option:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

Quoting their docs:

> The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic
>   types when compiling in JDK 5.0 and higher.

Comment: Perfect, googling "proguard type erasure" I was reading it here: http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/406/